# Spark Structured Streaming Run Final Operation on External Table (MSCK REPAIR)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

Is there a way in Spark's structured streaming to add a final operation to a `DataStreamWriter`'s query plan? I'm attempting to read from a streaming data source, enrich the data in some way, and then write back to a partitioned, external table (assume Hive) in parquet format. The write operation works just fine, partitioning the data in directories for me, but I can't seem to figure out how to additionally run an `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` operation after writing the data to disk for any new partitions that may have been created.

For simplicity's sake, take the following Scala code as an example:

```scala
SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("some name")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
  .readStream
  .format("text")
  .load("/path/from/somewhere")
  // additional transformations
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("some_column")
  .start("/path/to/somewhere")
   <--------------------  something I can place here for an additional operation?
  .awaitTermination()
```

*Potential workarounds?:*

<s>1: Maybe using something like `.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row])` and passing a `FileStreamSink` or something similar would work (using the `def close()` to run an external query), but I haven't looked into it enough to get a good grasp on using it.</s> - using ForeachWriter doesn't result in the `close()` method being called after a batch completes.

2: Forking the stream. Something along the lines of the following:

```scala
val stream = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("some name")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
  .readStream
  .format("text")
  .load("/path/from/somewhere")
  // additional transformations

stream
  .writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .partitionBy("some_column")
  .start("/path/to/somewhere")
  .awaitTermination()

stream
  .map(getPartitionName).distinct
  .map { partition =>

    // Run query here

    partition
  }
  .writeStream
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

The problem here would be ensuring the first operation completes before the second.

3: Naming the query and attaching a listener for completed batches which manually adds all partitions. A bit of a waste, but potentially viable?

```scala
...
stream
  .writeStream
  .queryName("SomeName")
...


spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {

  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = Unit
  override def onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    if (event.progress.name == "SomeName") {
      // search through files in filesystem and add partitions

      fileSystem.listDir("/path/to/directory").foreach { partition =>
        // run "ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION $partition"
      }
    }
  }
  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = Unit
})
```

I didn't see anything in the documentation that covers this, hopefully I didn't miss anything. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `StreamingQueryListener` works, though I'm not sure if it's good/bad practice.

I implemented something along the lines of this:

```
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {

  val client = new Client()

  override def onQueryStarted(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryStartedEvent): Unit = Unit
  override def onQueryTerminated(event: StreamingQueryListener.QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = Unit
  override def onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    if (event.progress.numInputRows > 0 && event.progress.sink.description.startsWith("FileSink") && event.progress.sink.description.contains("/path/to/write/directory")) {
      client.sql(s"MSCK REPAIR TABLE $db.$table")
    }
  }
})
```

If you happen to have time-based partitions, this works decently as long as you intend to create partitions based on `now()`:

```
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {

  val client = new Client()
  var lastPartition: String = ""
  val dateTimeFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd"

  override def onQueryStarted...
  override onQueryTerminated...
  override def onQueryProgress(event: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    if (event.progress.numInputRows > 0 && event.progress.sink.description.startsWith("FileSink[s3") && event.progress.sink.description.contains("/path/to/write/directory")) {

      val newPartition = new DateTime().toString(dateTimeFormat)

      if (newPartition != lastPartition) {
        client.sql(s"ALTER TABLE $db.$table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION ($partitionColumn='$newPartition')")
        lastPartition = newPartition
    }
  }
}
```